# Remove Blog margins (Simple Template)

Tags: html, mobile, width, blogger

My Blog (Simple Template) has 150px of margin on left & right sides.

I want no margin.

What my template has, as of now:

```
<meta expr:content='data:blog.isMobile ? &quot;width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0&quot; : &quot;width=1100&quot;' name='viewport'/>
```

Comment: I have just googled away. @TimTroiano

Comment: Edit your post with what you've tried and the relevant code to go with it otherwise we will not be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can use css margin code

like this:

```
.content-outer { 
    margin-top: X px;
    margin-bottom: X px;
    margin-left: X px;
    margin-right: X px;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your Blog under **Template> Customize> Advanced> Add CSS:**

```
.content-outer { 
    max-width: 100% !important; 
}
```